# How do I triangulate non-planar polygons correctly?

Tags: normals, 3d-modeling

I've got a super simple octagonal mesh with a bevel around the circumference. When I triangulate for export, the cuts form a valley (proper term here?) – which is to say, they transform a level quad into a pair of tris with some degree of concavity.

The resulting normal bake is horrific, as you might expect. Is this a nefarious rookie mistake I've tumbled into?

PS: For reference, here's before:
[image: Before triangulating.]

And here's after:
[image: After triangulating.]

Answer (score -1):

Oh. I was being unbelievably silly. There was no issue with concavity – my UV shells just needed to be exploded.

Comment: Could you explain what you have done in detail? This way, who has the same problem as you had, can solve it too ;)